# Capturar através do ExceptionHandler

Tags: java, java-ee, demoiselle

Estou tentando capturar uma `javax.validation.ValidationException` no meu MB para posteriormente jogar num alerta. Tentei com os três exemplos abaixo independentes mas nada retornou. Devo inserir mais algum código ? Utilizo a versão 2.5.0.

```
@ViewController
public class MeuMB extends AbstractEditPageBean<CTe, Long> {

@ExceptionHandler
public void tratar(RuntimeException ex) {
    System.out.println("1111" + ex);
}

@ExceptionHandler
public void tratar2(ValidationException ex) {
    System.out.println("2222" + ex);
}

@ExceptionHandler
public void tratar3(Exception ex) {
    System.out.println("3333" + ex);
}
```

---

A classe tem @ViewController e nela já chama o @Controller.

Meu método de chamada é o seguinte:

```
public String upload() {
    //int i = 5 / 0;

    try {
        this.gera();
    } catch (Exception ex) {  
        getMessageContext().add(getResourceBundle().getString("cte.msg.uploadFail"), SeverityType.ERROR);
        return null;
    }
```

Caso eu tirar o comentário de "5 / 0", ocorre erro e é chamado o RuntimeException. Portanto as chamadas e imports estariam ok.

Problema é que no método "gera" eu forço null num campo not null. Somente para testar.

```
@NotNull
@JoinColumn(name = "municipio_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private Municipio municipio;
```

E esse erro não estou conseguindo capturar nem no try catch nem pelas chamadas ExceptionHandler.

Answer (score 2):

A validação dispara uma `ConstraintViolationException` que pode ser encapsulada em `TransactionException`.

Então optei pela seguinte solução:

```
@ExceptionHandler
public void tratarErroInesperado(RuntimeException e) throws IOException {
    if (tratarConstraintViolationException(e)) {
        return;
    } else {
        ...
    }
}

private boolean tratarConstraintViolationException(Exception e) {
    Throwable cause = e;
    while (cause != null) {
        if (cause instanceof ConstraintViolationException) {
            for (ConstraintViolation<?> violation : cve.getConstraintViolations()) {
                messageContext.add(violation.getMessage(), SeverityType.ERROR);
            }
            return true;
        }
        cause = cause.equals(cause.getCause()) ? null : cause.getCause();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

De acordo com a documentação, esses métodos só serão invocados se a exceção ocorrer em algum outro método, nesse caso da classe MeuMB, para testar é necessário criar um outro método e provocar a exceção.

```
@Controller
public class Simples {

    @ExceptionHandler
    public void tratador(NullPointerException cause) { }

    @ExceptionHandler
    public void tratador(AbacaxiException cause) { }    

    public void inserir() { }   

    public void alterar() { }   

    public void excluir() { }   
}
```

> Caso as exceções NullPointerException ou AbacaxiException ocorram nos
>   métodos da classe Simples, o tratamento será delegado para o seu
>   tratador.

http://demoiselle.sourceforge.net/docs/framework/reference/2.5.0-RC1/html_single/#d0e1029